# List of edges that don't exist in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a `networkx` graph. With `G.edges()` I can get a list of all the edges. But is there a way to get a list of all other non-existing edges? So if there are 3 nodes: a, b, c and we suppose a and b are connected only, then I would like to get a list of edges that don't exist, so like this: `(a,c), (c,b)`. Is there an easy pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [Ezekiel Kruglick shows a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859628/190597) to do this, now that networkx has a`non_edges` (and also a `non-neighbors`) function.

---

You could iterate through all possible edges using `itertools.combinations`, and check if it is not an edge in G using `G.has_edge`:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools as IT
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')])

missing = [pair for pair in IT.combinations(G.nodes(), 2)
           if not G.has_edge(*pair)]
print(missing)
```

yields

```
[('A', 'C')]
```

Comment: isn't `G.has_edge()` a linear search? this would be slow I guess!!

Comment: No, `G.has_edges` tries to look up the edge in the `G.adj` adjacency dict. So the lookup is O(1).

Comment: Check Ezekiel's answer for the "new" built-in networkx function

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a new function in networkx 1.9 called [non_edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/functions.html) just for this purpose:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')])
list(nx.non_edges(G))

Out[3]:
[('A', 'C')]
```

I've put non_edges into a `list()` command here to materialize the output, as `nx.non_edges` is a generator. Having a generator can be very helpful when handling large graphs.

Answer (score 1):

@unutbu's answer is likely the most efficient way.  You could also generate the complement graph and emit the edges.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx                                                           

In [2]: G = nx.Graph([('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')])                                          

In [3]: print(nx.complement(G).edges()) 
[('A', 'C')]
```